# How does Zapier/IFTTT implement the triggers and actions for different API providers?

Tags: mashup, zapier

How does Zapier/IFTTT implement the triggers and actions for different API providers? Is there any generic approach to do that, or they are implemented by individual?

I think the implementation is based on REST/Oauth, that is generic from high level to see. But  for Zapier/IFTTT, it defines a lot of trigger conditions, filters. These conditions, filters should be specific to different provider. Is the corresponding implementation in individual or in generic? If in individual, there must be a vast labor force. If in generic, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Zapier developer here - the short answer is, we implement each one!

While standards like OAuth make it easier to reuse some of the code from one API to another, there is no getting around the fact that each API has unique endpoints and unique requirements. What works for one API will not necessarily work for another. Internally, we have abstracted away as much of the process as we can into reusable bits, but there is always some work involved to add a new API.

Comment: @brianC How is the database for zaps set up? I'm trying to set up something similar and would love some insights! like I have tblSequences and tblSequenceItems and tblSequenceTriggers. The triggers and items will have to have all these database entries for service1Secret, service2Secret, etc. depending on what trigger and item it is.

Answer (score 2):

PipeThru developer here...

There are common elements to each API which can be re-used, such as OAuth authentication, common data formats (JSON, XML, etc). Most APIs strive for a RESTful implementation. However, theory meets reality and most APIs are all over the place.

Each services offers its own endpoints and there are no commonly agreed upon set of endpoints that are correct for given services. For example, within CRM software, its not clear how a person, notes on said person, corresponding phone numbers, addresses, as well as activities should be represented. Do you provide one endpoint or several? How do you update each? Do you provide tangential records (like the company for the person) with the record or not? Each requires specific knowledge of that service as well as some data normalization.

Most of the triggers involve checking for a new record (unique id), or an updated field, most usually the last update timestamp. Most services present their timestamps in ISO 8601 format which makes parsing timestamp easy, but not everyone. Dropbox actually provides a delta API endpoint to which you can present a hash value and Dropbox will send you everything new/changed from that point. I love to see delta and/or activity endpoints in more APIs.

Bottom line, integrating each individual service does require a good amount of effort and testing.

I will point out that Zapier did implement an API for other companies to plug into their tool. Instead of Zapier implementing your API and Zapier polling you for data, you can send new/updated data to Zapier to trigger one of their Zaps. I like to think of this like webhooks on crack. This allows Zapier to support many more services without having to program each one.

Comment: @andyJones I was wondering if you have any info about setting up the database for sequences and triggers. What would be the best way to set it up. Currently i have tblsequences, tblSequenceItems and tblSequenceTriggers ? Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a few APIs on Zapier, so I think I can provide at least a partial answer here. If not using webhooks, Zapier will examine the API response from a service for the field with the shortest name that also includes the string "id". Changes to this field cause Zapier to trigger a task. This is based off the assumption that an id is usually incremental or random.

I've had to work around this by shifting the id value to another field and writing different values to id when it was failing to trigger, or triggering too frequently (dividing by 10 and then writing id can reduce the trigger sensitivity, for example). Ambiguity is also a problem, for example in an API response that contains fields like post_id and mesg_id.

Short answer is that the system makes an educated guess, but to get it working reliably for a specific service, you should be quite specific in your code regarding what constitutes a trigger event.